# Is there a way you can decrement an array in a periodic fashion in C

Tags: c

i'm writing a code for a number on a led  segement to decrease by 1 every five seconds

my actual code at the moment is this

```
FiveSecDelay+=1;
if (FiveSecDelay ==100)
{
count2--; //decrement count2

for (uint32_t x = 0; x < 4; x++) //split count to to individual digits
{
new_value[x] = count2 % 10;
count2 = count2 / 10;
}

for (uint32_t i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{

Segment_Write(Digit[i],new_value[i]); assign  value to segments
}
FiveSecDelay =0;
}
```

im using a schedular to call a function every milisecond, in theory this supposed to work as i used the same technique to assign a value to the segments, 
what happens is that i have a starting value of 8, and it supposed to got 7,6,5,4 and so on till 0, but for some reason it goes from 8 to 42 and stays there

I had tried to fix it but have come up short.

Any help would be great

Thank you

Comment: We need vastly more information. C itself is just a programming language. What environment are you operating under? Is this on a microprocessor? Is this Win32?

Comment: Is your confusion with the timing? Or is it with how to decrement an integer in an array?

Comment: @user Do you have problem with the decrement (or) call the function periodically ?

Comment: *"i'm writing a code for a number on a led segement to decrease by 1 every **two** seconds"* glad to hear that: if it had been "by 1 **every** second" someone might have thought you were making some kind of bomb timer... :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void check() {
  static int array[] = {142}; // why are you using an array here?
  (*array)--;
}

int main() {
  while(true)
  {
    check();
    usleep(5000); // approximate
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty way:

```
while(true)
{
    check();
    sleep(5);
}


int values[1];
int check(void)
{
    if (values[0] > 0)
       values[0]--;
}
```

Comment: You could just use a static int instead of an array if you're only decrementing one value each time around the loop too.

Comment: Technically, this does not decrement the value every 5 ms. This waits 5ms between each decrementation. There's a difference.

Comment: @Artefact2 True, which is why it's 'quick and dirty' but it gives an idea of how to achieve the desired result :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the system time, you can store the initial time the call was made, and then every time you query its value, check against the system time to determine the correct adjusted value, and a little snippet to set the value, like such:

```
// initialize
int check = 142;
unsigned long long time = getMillis();

int get_value(void)
{
    unsigned long long time_factor = ((getMillis() - time) / (unsigned long long) 5);
    if (time_factor > (unsigned long long) check)
        return 0;
    else
        return check - time_factor;
}

void set_value(int v)
{
    check = v;
    time = getMillis();
}
```

Note that I don't know off the top of my head how to get the system time in c (though I bet you'd need `#include <time.h>`) so I made up a function called getMillis() which returns the system time as an unsigned long long (should be a 64 bit unsigned integer).  The implementation is up to the reader.

It's also worth mentioning that you will experience a wraparound error after about 600 million years.

Answer (score 0):

Have `check` take a parameter which is the number. Then have a counter in the main loop of your program that starts at some value, and is decremented every time check is called.

I'm assuming that you are doing something more complex than what your current `check` function does because obviously it doesn't do anything in the provided form. If you provide more information, we would be able to give you a more thorough and applicable solution.

Comment: the check function was just an example, i have tried what you suggested , but it didn't work,

Comment: @user1175889 in what way did it not work? What is the problem that you are having?

Comment: What i am doing is controlling 4 led segments, to which a value is written, that value is then decremented by 1 every 5 seconds

Comment: @user1175889 Ok, so what is the wrong thing that is currently happening? Could you provide a little more code?

Comment: The compiler is not letting me assign the whole value to the segments, have to assign one digit at a time

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't the decrementing at all. It's handling the number. I assume that you're programming for an Intel 8031 microcontroller or something like that. You'll need to extract the digits from the number that you pass in by (for example) taking the number mod 10 for the 1s place, dividing by 10, then doing the same for the 10s place, etc.

Comment: oh do u mean something like this `for (uint32_t x = 0; x < 4; x++)
  {
   new_value[x] = count2 % 10;
   count2 = count2 / 10; 
  }`count2 is the value i want to assign